# Can strings change spacetime topology?

Tags: spacetime, string-theory, topology

There are two broad ways of looking at spacetime in string theory:

1. You can consider strings moving on some background geometry via the usual non-linear sigma-model (of course the presence of string excitations can then warp your geometry).
2. You can start with a flat background and inject in a coherent state of string excitations to reproduce exactly the original background you were looking at.

In other words, $\textit{any}$ geometry satisfying the stringy-corrected Einstein equations can be thought of as a coherent state of strings in flat space. My question is now: does this hold for spaces with non-trivial topology? For example, can I get a background with non-trivial 2-cycles (and thus worldsheet instantons) by just injecting some string excitations into flat space? Of course I don't think this is true, but if it fails then it seems to invalidate the claims by some that string theory is background independent, since in a sense all backgrounds are hidden somewhere inside it. What's going wrong here?

Note that I'm not talking about spacetime topology phase changes a la Aspinwall, Greene, and Morrison. Rather I'm asking if every topology, subject to some constraints analogous to string-corrected Ricci-flatness, can be reached via string excitations.

Comment: At low energy, where the excitations of the string are perturbations of the metric, propagating on the background spacetime this is, I think, certainly not true. I don't know if this happens when one would include the stringy corrections, in which case the effective dynamics of the spacetime geometry is described by a Lagrangian involving many complicated higher order terms. I am guessing your question, in that case, comes down to whether it is possible for a metric to change its topology when it's dynamics is described by such a Lagrangian with many higher order terms in the curvature.

Comment: General Relativity cannot say (nearly) anything about the topology, at best there are theorems forbidding topology change (classically).  So it seems to me that different topological sector don't talk each other, and to get a genus 1 geometry you should exponentiate "genus 1 string excitations", if this makes sense. Looking at the vertex operator of a graviton in string theory, I don't see where this information on the topology can come from.